# Not able to read pipe delimited csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input data:

```
Ord_value|other_data
12345|u1=876435;u5=4356|4357|4358;u15=Mr. Noodles,n/a,Great Value;u16=0.77,4.92,7.96;u17=4,1,7;
```

Details of U variables

```
U1= order I'd --single value
U5= pid --is a list
U15= name --is a list
U16= price -- is a list
U17= quantity -- is a list
```

Output:

```
Ord_value|orderid|pid|name|price|quantity
12345|876435|4356|Mr. Noodles|0.77|4
12345|876435|4357|n/a|4.92|1
```

i tried reading the file using semi colon

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object example3 {
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop\\")
      val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("first_demo").setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
       val spark=SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("Error")
      import spark.implicits._
    // val rdd1=sc.textFile("file:///C://Users//User//Desktop//example3.txt")
    // rdd1.map(x=>x.split(";")).foreach(println)
      spark.read.option("delimiter",";").option("header","true").load("file:///C://Users//User//Desktop//example3.txt").show()
}
}
```

Not able to read the file. am getting above error. it looks like complex file.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/example3.txt; isDirectory=false; length=95; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
```

i tried again

val df1=spark.read.option("delimiter","|").csv("file:///C://Users//User//Desktop//example3.txt")

```
+-----+-----------------+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_c0  |_c1              |_c2 |_c3                                                               |
+-----+-----------------+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|12345|u1=876435;u5=4356|4357|4358;u15=Mr. Noodles,n/a,Great Value;u16=0.77,4.92,7.96;u17=4,1,7;|
+-----+-----------------+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You need to use `.csv`, not `.load`, which expects Parquet files, I believe

Comment: actually i was trying to split using semi colon

Comment: Your columns (Ord_value|other_data) are not separated by semi colons. You can split the dataframe columns into more columns after you read the file correctly

Comment: so i have to split from first pipe delimiter.. may i know how to recognize the first pipe delimiter

Comment: What you had before was correct `option("delimiter","|").option("header","true")` but you either need another option for `format:csv` or use `.csv("file path")`